# Shell: Unexpected End of File

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to find where I might have a mismatched tag or quotation, but it is eluding me.  The error I am receiving is unexpected EOF at line 48, which only tells me what I already know.  Here is my simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Program to output a system information page

TITLE="System Information for $HOSTNAME"

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%x %r %Z")
TIME_STAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, by $USER"

report_uptime () {
    cat <<- _EOF_
        <H2>System Uptime</H2>
        <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
        _EOF_
    return
}

report_disk_space () {
    cat <<- _EOF_
        <H2>Disk Space Utilization</H2>
        <PRE>$(df -h)</PRE>
        _EOF_
    return
}

report_home_space () {
    cat <<- _EOF_
        <H2>Home Space Utilization</H2>
        <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
        _EOF_
    return
}

cat << _EOF_
<HTML>
        <HEAD>
                <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
                <H1>$TITLE</H1>
                <P>$TIME_STAMP</P>
                $(report_uptime)
                $(report_disk_space)
                $(report_home_space)
        </BODY>
</HTML>
_EOF_
```

Comment: Are the `_EOF_` indented with actual tab characters? If they're not, then bash won't honor them. indenting with spaces means bash will never see the _EOF_ terminator and run off the end of the script. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-nestings-indent

Comment: I think I have my tabstops set to 4 spaces rather than a tab due to Python, but I thought the <<- negated this?

Comment: yea, but the indents HAVE to use actual tabs. spaces-that-your-editor-treats-as-tabs won't work. bash couldn't care less which editor you used, it only sees what's in the file, and what's in the file has to be actual tab chars (ascii 9) and not spaces (ascii 32). `<<-` allows indenting the terminator, but doesn't magically make spaces work as the indent char.

Comment: Marc I would choose your answer if I could.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using spaces instead of tabs <<- doesn't work with with spaces.